# How to pass additional variables to anonymous TableGateway method arguments?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

I have my modelTable, all works fine, but I am trying to pass some variable to function and the variable is not recognized.

My function in Application/Model/someTable.php

```
/**
 * @param array $myWhere
 * @param $myOrder
 * @return \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet
 */
public function fetchAllPagination(Array $myWhere,$myOrder)
{

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){

        $select->where(function(Where $where){
            $where->equalTo($myWhere[0],$myWhere[1]);
        });

        $select->order($myOrder);
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Call it into controller

```
    $all = $someTable->fetchAllPagination(array('id_user'=>$identity->users_id),'insert_date ASC');
```

The problem is that the variables `$myWhere` and `$myOrder` are not recognised inside the `function(Select $select)` and I have a SQL ERROR:

> Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= NULL ORDER BY  ASC' at line 1)

How can I solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: Also, on solve my problem I see that I was doing an error too, I was calling the funcion in controller wrong way:    `$someTable->fetchAllPagination(array('id_user'=>$identity->users_id),'insert_date ASC');`  and I have to call it with this array:  ` $someTable->fetchAllPagination(array('id_user',$identity->users_id),'insert_date ASC');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the ZF2 here. Since arguments of the `select()` and `where()` methods are instances of a [closure](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), both `$myWhere` and `$myOrder` arguments are out of the scope. Closures has no access to the scope in which it is defined or executed.

Anyway, you can try to passing additinal variables with `use` keyword (language struct) something like this:

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(
    function(Select $select) use ($myOrder) {
        $select->where(
            function(Where $where) use ($myWhere) {
                $where->equalTo($myWhere[0],$myWhere[1]);
        });
$select->order($myOrder);
});
```

You may want to read more about [anonymous functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in official documentation.

Comment: That works fine for me, also I saw the doc and understand more about it, Thanks for help. I only have to add the variable $myWhere in Select function too.